# When zoomed, UWP ListView stops centering content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ListView populated with InkCanvases, each representing a page. I've set the ListView to be scrollable like so:

```xml
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="canvases"
    SelectionMode="None"
    ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
```

And the ListView is populated in a corresponding c# file:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
{
    InkCanvas canvas = new InkCanvas();
    canvas.Width = 720;
    canvas.Height = 1080;
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.Width = canvas.Width;
    grid.Height = canvas.Height;
    grid.Children.Add(canvas);
    grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Content = grid;
    item.Width = canvas.Width;
    item.Height = canvas.Height;
    canvases.Items.Add(item);

    addCanvas(canvas);
}
```

Now, when I run the program the view is initially centered, but when I scroll out it shifts left:

[image]

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ37N.jpg)

To be clear, I'm not trying to center the ListView inside its parent, I'm trying to center the content of the ListView, and preserve the centering of the children when the user zooms out. In the end result I hope for the ListView to horizontally fill the window, and for the user to be able to zoom in and out on the ListView, and for the zoomed out ListView to have its items be centered.

The desired output is identical to the zooming in the program Drawboard, this can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1DZL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end all it took was to wrap the ListView in a separate ScrollViewer with a Viewbox.

```xml
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="0.25">
    <Viewbox>
        <ListView SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <InkCanvas/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Viewbox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the style of the ListView a little bit.

1. Find the Default style of the ListView in Generic.xaml
2. Find the **ScrollViewer** Element which is named `ScrollViewer` in the default style.
3. Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `ScrollViewer` to **Center**
4. Remove the `HorizontalContentAlignment` you set for the ListView.
5. Run the app and you will get the behavior you want.

**Style Xaml here:**

```
    <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <ScrollViewer  x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                      BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                      IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" 
                                      IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                      IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                      IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" 
                                      IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                      TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" 
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                            <ItemsPresenter Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                                            FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" 
                                            FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                            HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" 
                                            
                                            
                                            Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**MainPage Xaml:**

```
   <Grid Background="Black">
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}"
x:Name="canvases"
SelectionMode="None"
ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: This solution works for zooming out but doesn't work when I zoom in. I've updated the original post to make it clearer what specifically I'm trying to achieve. The problem that I face with your solution is that the ListView does not horizontally fill the window, and so when I zoom in the canvases are clipped.

Comment: @ZevG I'm confused about your description. Please share an image of the expected behavior you want with me to help me understand your requirement.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding, I've updated the problem with a link to a video displaying the desired result.

Comment: @ZevG Do you mean when you zoom out the scrollviewer, you need the content fill all the space of a listview item even though the zoom value less than its original value? Just make the content maximize the item once you zoom out?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delayed response I've been pretty busy lately. I was able to find a solution using a ViewBox. I'll write out an answer to the question later today.